# Websites with different tax classes for one country

Tags: multistore, tax

What is the best way to have different taxes in different websites for one country?

**Scenario:**

Website 1:

- Tax Rate for Germany -> 19%
- Tax Rate for Austria -> 20%

Website 2:

- Tax Rate for Germany -> 19%
- Tax Rate for Austria -> 19%

The only way I see is to create a new product tax class for website 2. I would then add a tax rule with a tax rate of 19% for Austria and set the new product tax class to all products of website 2.

Is this the correct way or are there any other possibilites?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

I also have to set in **system -> sales -> shipping settings -> origin country** to the other country. Its not enought to change the Default Tax Destination Calculation Country and define the tax rules.

and visit link:-http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/managing-taxes

Comment: The problem is that there are more countries available on every website, not only Austria. When I change the origin country, the taxes for the other countries would be incorrect.